# rsync read `--files-from` from bash array instead of file

Tags: rsync

Is it possible to get rsync to read a list of file to include from an array in the active script rather than a accompanying file?

```
## declare an array variable
declare -a files=("path" "path" "path")

rsync --files-from=${files[@]} source destination
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'd like to have just one script file to manage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can execute :

```
`rsync --files-from=<( printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}" ) source destination
```

- `<()` wil open a pipe and fill it with the content of the inner command. It returns a file descriptor
- `printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}"` echo each file name in a different line

Comment: Thanks @vera. Unfortunately I'm getting this:`+ myFiles=(1\n 2\n 3\n)
+ rsync -avh --files-from=/dev/fd/63 /foo/ /bar/
++ echo -e 1n 2n 3n
building file list ... 
rsync: link_stat "/foo/1n 2n 3n" failed: No such file or directory (2)
0 files to consider
`

Comment: Ok, I see the problem: you can use printf instead of echo, then you do not have to add the trailing "\n". I edited the answer.

Comment: For me this doesn't work i got error with break-lines interpreted as #012.
I had to use null character  : `rsync --files-from=<( printf "%s\0" "${files[@]}" ) --from0 source destination`